# Amplify AWS API function Problem when get Cognito User

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I was working Amplify to get Cognito Users.

I was googling and I found one code using this which is recommended by many users.

```
let users = await cognitoClient.listUsers(request).promise();
```

Other users all said this works but it does not work on my side.

Instead of it this code works for me.

```
cognitoClient.listUsers(request, funtion(error, data){
...
})
```

Please let me know if my node js version have problem

Comment: `async / await` was enabled by default in node version 7.6. But it was possible to use it in previous versions using the `--harmony` flag. Is the `await` line contained in a function marked with the `async` keyword? It's difficult to debug the issue without you specifying what errors you got when you tried to use it.